# How can I request parameters in api gateway using cloudformation in aws and pass it down to lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to request parameters using API Gateway in AWS CloudFormation. The parameter that I want to pass down from API gateway to Lambda function is 'action'. I have tried the following code and so far I ran into the error, mention below. Can someone please help me with identifying the issue and a possible resolution?

"Invalid mapping expression specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [Invalid mapping expression specified: Integration.request.path.action] (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Request ID: 037f4753-52b5-4276-979a-131a0f903e63)"

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: "API Gateway and Lambda function"

Resources:
  SampleApi:
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi"
    Properties:
      Name: Sample

  SampleApiMethod:
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Method"
    Properties:
      AuthorizationType: "NONE"
      HttpMethod: "GET"
      RequestParameters:
        method.request.path.action: true
      RequestTemplates:
        application/yaml
      Integration:
        IntegrationHttpMethod: "POST"
        Type: "AWS_PROXY"
        RequestParameters:
          Integration.request.path.action: method.request.path.action 
        Uri: !Sub
          - "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${lambdaArn}/invocations"
          - lambdaArn: !GetAtt "SampleLambda.Arn"
        CacheKeyParameters:
          - method.request.path.action
      ResourceId: !GetAtt "SampleApi.RootResourceId"
      RestApiId: !Ref "SampleApi"

  SampleApiDeployment:
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment"
    DependsOn: "SampleApiMethod"
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref "SampleApi"
      StageName: test

  SampleLambda:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Function"
    Properties:
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
            import yaml
            import boto3
            cf_client = boto3.client('cloudformation')
            cf_client.create_stack(
                StackName='your-stack',
                TemplateURL='Some URL',
                Parameters=[
                    {
                        'ParameterKey':'action',
                        'ParameterValue': 'kms:*'
                    },
                ]
            )
      Handler: "index.handler"
      Role: !GetAtt "SampleLambdaRole.Arn"
      Runtime: python3.7

  LambdaApiGatewayInvoke:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Permission"
    Properties:
      Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
      FunctionName: !GetAtt "SampleLambda.Arn"
      Principal: "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      SourceArn: !Sub "arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${SampleApi}/*/GET/"

  SampleLambdaRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Action: ["sts:AssumeRole"]
            Effect: "Allow"
            Principal:
              Service: ["lambda.amazonaws.com"]
      Policies:
        - PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Action: ["cloudwatch:*", "logs:*"]
                Effect: "Allow"
                Resource: "*"
          PolicyName: "lambdaLogPolicy"  
Outputs:
  apiGatewayInvokeURL:
    Value: !Sub 'https://Sample.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/test'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the docs, the key for `RequestParameters` should be like `integration.request.<location>.<name>`, with a lowercase `i` for `integration`. You are using an uppercase `I`. From the [AWS CloudFormation docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apitgateway-method-integration.html#cfn-apigateway-method-integration-requestparameters):

> Specify the destination by using the following pattern `integration.request.location.name`, where `location` is query string, path, or header, and `name` is a valid, unique parameter name.

Also, your template from above contains a `RequestTemplates` property which is placed in the wrong hierarchy level. It must be placed below `Integration` as noted in the [AWS CloudFormation docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apitgateway-method-integration.html#cfn-apigateway-method-integration-requesttemplates) as well. Here is the correct template for `AWS::ApiGateway::Method` for you:

```
SampleApiMethod:
  Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Method"
  Properties:
    AuthorizationType: "NONE"
    HttpMethod: "GET"
    RequestParameters:
      method.request.path.action: true
    Integration:
      IntegrationHttpMethod: "POST"
      Type: "AWS_PROXY"
      RequestParameters:
        integration.request.path.action: method.request.path.action
      RequestTemplates:
        "application/yaml": "<define your template here>"
      Uri: !Sub
        - "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${lambdaArn}/invocations"
        - lambdaArn: !GetAtt "SampleLambda.Arn"
      CacheKeyParameters:
        - method.request.path.action
    ResourceId: !GetAtt "SampleApi.RootResourceId"
    RestApiId: !Ref "SampleApi"
```

More information about *defining a request template* can be found in the [developer reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html).